# Full Outer Join in Access while counting the items

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a full outer join in Access while counting the items and getting the percentage.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Main.Draft, Count(Main.Draft) AS MainCount, (Count([Main.Draft])/(Select Count(Main.Draft) from Main)) AS Percentage
FROM Main LEFT JOIN Main_ChangeLog ON Main.ID = Main_ChangeLog.ID
GROUP BY Main.Draft;
UNION ALL 
SELECT Main.Draft, Count(Main.Draft) AS MainCount, (Count([Main.Draft])/(Select Count(Main.Draft) from Main)) AS Percentage
FROM Main RIGHT JOIN Main_ChangeLog ON Main.ID = Main_ChangeLog.ID
WHERE (((Main.Date) Between [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtbegin] And [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtend]))
GROUP BY Main.Draft;
```

Here is my outcome:

```
Version_1   1   0
Version_2   1   0   
Version_3   3   0
Version_1   4   0
Version_2   3   0
```

Here is the outcome I want:

```
Version_1   5   0.50
Version_2   4   0.15
Version_3   3   0.35
```

Here is the Main table:

```
ID  CreateDate  FirstName   LastName   Draft

1   10/01/2020   First       One        Version_2
2   11/20/2020   Second      Person     Version_3
3   11/20/2020   Third       Girl       Version_3
4   11/21/2020   Fourth      Boy        Version_3
5   11/22/2020   Fifth       Guy        Version_1
```

Here is the Main_ChangeLog table:

```
ID CreateDate    FirstName   LasteName   Draft
1  9/10/2020      First       One       Version_1
2  9/10/2020      Second      Person    Version_1
2  10/10/2020     Second      Person    Version_2
3  9/10/2020      Third       Girl      Version_1
3  10/10/2020     Third       Girl      Version_2
4  9/5/2020       Fourth      Boy       Version_1
4  10/10/2020     Fourth      Boy       Version_2
```

Everytime a record is updated on the Main table the previous record is stored in the Main_ChangeLog.  It helps to get a true idea of how many versions were created each month.

I just modified my code to this:

```
  SELECT t.Draft, Count(t.Count) AS DraftCount, (Count(t.Draft)/(Select Count(t.Draft) from Main)) AS [Percentage]
    FROM 
    (SELECT Main.Draft as Draft, Main.Draft as [Count]
    FROM MainLEFT JOIN Main_ChangeLog ON Main.ID = Main_ChangeLog.ID 
    WHERE (((Main.Date) Between [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtbegin] And [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtend]))
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Main.Draft AS Draft, Main.Draft as [Count]
    FROM MainRIGHT JOIN Main_ChangeLog ON Main.ID = Main_ChangeLog.ID
    WHERE (((Main.Date) Between [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtbegin] And [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtend])))  AS t
    GROUP BY t.Draft
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the data in the tables.  It is hard to follow the calculations.  How are the fractions calculated?  And describe the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Perform `union all` first and group on results.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work because I have aggregate function in both queries.  I even tried moving the aggregate functions to the bottom query but, that didn't work either.

Comment: How are the desired percentages calculated like the 50% for `version_`1? I can see 1/5 or 5/12.

Comment: I am trying to divide the total of the selected draft by the total of all drafts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way of getting it done with two queries:

1. The first query(which we'll call `qryMainData`) will join all of your version data together, using the `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID, Draft, CreateDate FROM Main
UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, Draft, CreateDate FROM Main_ChangeLog;
```

2. the second query will be based on the first, because you want to use the total count of the entire result set of query 1 (`qryMainData`) to calculate the percentages:

```
SELECT Draft, Count(ID) as DraftQty, (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM qryMainData) as TotalDraftQty,
ROUND(DraftQty/TotalDraftQty, 2) as DraftPercentage
FROM qryMainData
WHERE CreateDate Between [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtbegin] And [Forms]![Main Reports]![txtend]
GROUP BY Draft
```

MS Access allows you to use the field aliases in the calculations. I also used the `ROUND` function to round the results to two decimal places.